# How to create an AD User with a Powershell GUI?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I am trying to create a GUI that can create new AD Users. 
My Problem: When I press the Button "Speichern" it does not use the Data in the textboxs to create the AD User. Instead this text comes in the command console:

```
New ADUser cmdlet at command pipeline location 1
Specify values ​​for the following parameters:
Surname:
```

If I enter the Surname it will create the User with this Surname.
This is my Powershell script:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#GUI Oberfläche
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,500)
$Form.Text = "Benutzer hinzufügen"

#-------Labels-----------
#Label Benutzer hinzufügen
$labeladduser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$labeladduser.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,10) 
$labeladduser.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,30) 
$labeladduser.Text = "Benutzer hinzufügen"
$labeladduser.Name = "Benutzer hinzufügen"
$Form.Controls.Add($labeladduser)

#Label Vorname
$Labelvorname = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Labelvorname.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,50) 
$Labelvorname.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20) 
$Labelvorname.Text = "Vorname"
$Labelvorname.Name = "Vorname"
$Form.Controls.Add($Labelvorname)

#Label Nachname
$Labelnachname = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Labelnachname.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,80) 
$Labelnachname.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20) 
$Labelnachname.Text = "Nachname"
$Labelnachname.Name = "Nachname"
$Form.Controls.Add($Labelnachname)

#Label Vollständigername
$LabelVn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$LabelVn.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,110) 
$LabelVn.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20) 
$LabelVn.Text = "Vollständigername"
$LabelVn.Name = "Vollständigername"
$Form.Controls.Add($LabelVn)

#Label Benutzeranmeldename
$LabelBa = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$LabelBa.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,140) 
$LabelBa.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20) 
$LabelBa.Text = "Benutzeranmeldename"
$LabelBa.Name = "Benutzeranmeldename"
$Form.Controls.Add($LabelBa)

#-------Buttons-------
#Close GUI Button
$BTcancel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$BTcancel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,180)
$BTcancel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$BTcancel.Text = "Cancel"
$BTcancel.Name = "Cancel"
$BTcancel.Add_Click({$Form.Close()})
$Form.Controls.Add($BTcancel) 

#Speichern Button
$BTsave = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$BTsave.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,180)
$BTsave.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$BTsave.Text = "Speichern"
$BTsave.Name = "Speichern"
$Form.Controls.Add($BTsave) 

#------Textfields------
#Textfeld Vorname
$Textboxvorname = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$Textboxvorname.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,50) 
$Textboxvorname.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20) 
$addv = $Textboxvorname.Text
$Form.Controls.Add($Textboxvorname)

#Textfeld Nachname
$Textboxnachname = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$Textboxnachname.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,80) 
$Textboxnachname.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20) 
$addn = $Textboxnachname.Text
$Form.Controls.Add($Textboxnachname)

#Textfeld Vollständigername
$TextboxVa = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$TextboxVa.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,110) 
$TextboxVa.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20) 
$addVa = $TextboxVa.Text
$Form.Controls.Add($TextboxVa)

#Textfeld Benutzeranmeldename
$TextboxBa= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$TextboxBa.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,140) 
$TextboxBa.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20) 
$addBa = $TextboxBa.Text
$Form.Controls.Add($TextboxBa)

#------Funktionen--------
#Add User
$BTsave.Add_Click({
New-ADuser
 -Name $addVa
 -Path "Ou=Users, DC=domain, DC=com"
 -Givenname = $addv
 -Surname =$addn
 -SamAccountName $addBa
 -AccountPassword (ConvertT0-SecureString "<redacted>" -AsPlainText -Force)
})

[void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

[image]
Does someone have a solution for my problem?

Comment: try `$addVa.Text` instead of just `$addVa`

Comment: doesent  make a differnece

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *believe* the problem is when you are assigning values.

taking this as an example:

```
#Textfeld Benutzeranmeldename
$TextboxBa= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$TextboxBa.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,140) 
$TextboxBa.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20) 
$addBa = $TextboxBa.Text
$Form.Controls.Add($TextboxBa)
```

when you're assigning a value to `$addBa` the value of `$TextboxBa.Text` is most likely empty!

So you should probably change your `$BTsave.Add_Click` event to directly access the textbox value(s) rather than the empty variable.

Also worth noting is that PowerShell doesn't take kindly to line breaks. If you want to avoid long lines you have to add a back-tick character.

```
#Add User
$BTsave.Add_Click({
    New-ADuser `
        -Name $TextboxVa.Text `
        -Path "Ou=Users, DC=domain, DC=com" `
        -Givenname $Textboxvorname.Text `
        -Surname $Textboxnachname.Text `
        -SamAccountName $TextboxBa.Text `
        -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "<redacted>" -AsPlainText -Force)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Below has a full form.

Create User and add to groups.
[NewUserForm PowershellGUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqRPd.png)
https://github.com/jcvnstdn/jcvnstdn/blob/main/UserCreationForm.PS1